# nginx $document_root not evaluating root directive regex

Tags: nginx

My goal is to have wildcard subdomains that each serve php from their own directory.  For instance, the "www" subdomain serves from "public_html/www" and "blog" serves from "public_html/blog."  Here is my curent nginx config that allows this to partially work:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$;

    root        /var/www/example.com/public_html/$1;
    index       index.php index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

To test, I have an index.php in the www directory and index.htm in the blog directory.  The blog subdomain works fine and displays the index.htm from the blog directory.

However, the www subdomain does not work and the page returns "No input file specified."  If I hardcode the "www" into the root directive instead of the "$1" it works for the "www" subdomain, but then of course blog also displays that content.

So, it seems as though the $document_root inside the php-specific location isn't evaluating the $1 of the root directive that represents the subdomain.  What needs to change or how do I ensure the root is evaluated when using $document_root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a named capture rather than a numeric capture.

```
server_name ~^(?<subsystem>.+)\.example\.com$;
root        /var/www/example.com/public_html/$subsystem;
```

Maybe `root` is evaluated late (I don't know) and the `$1` is overwritten by the `location` regex.

Comment: Looks like that did it!  I'm going to continue with a little further testing later but for right now, that change alone removed the error and displayed my content.  Thanks!